# Retrieve links from a gSite?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to read out the links from internal gSites, because editors still forget to enter the addresses in a simple gSheet. The links change often and we get broken links every months.
Therefore I wanna write a link-checker which retrives all links of a given page. I tried to read out the html code from the site by using UrlFetchApp, but don't receive the site html. I receive a html code with Google login to access the given page, but not the html of the intranet page. I I guess that is related to Google Server which runs the fetch which is placed in the Internet. Of course I could save the html code as file and use it as page source but I would like to have it a little bit smarter.

I appreciate all suggestions.

Warm regards

Comment: Is this question  about Classic or new Google Sites? Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [askl].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Different departments created for their department new are new Google Sites which are only internally visible.
We have often changing links. Means those tend to break. So I wanna read out the links and after retrieving I wanna check the links. If they are broken I can inform them that they have to update the links.
Actually no big issue. But all the stuff is in our intranet and it seems that it fails because the google server doing the job is outside our intranet. 
So the question is what can I do from the intranet side to get it run?

Answer (score 0):

There's this example in the documentation:

```
// This writes the first page of sites belonging to a Google Workspace
// domain to the log.
var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites("examplepetstore.com.");
for(var i in sites) {
  Logger.log(sites[i].getUrl());
}
```

[GetAllSites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app?hl=en#getAllSites(String))

[Sites Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app?hl=en)

Comment: Hi Cooper,

yes this works fine, but unfortunately not for sites in our intranet. So I can't retrieve these links. 
But thanks for your hint, so I can develop the further code to retrieve the link till I have the possibility to connect to internal sites.

Warm regards